# Running an script AS USER after resuming from suspend

Tags: systemd, audio, users, root, suspend

Every time my computer resumes from a suspend (which I do quite often) the audio gets a bit messed up. I use the EasyEffects EQ on my computer and it runs on startup to apply the EQ. When my computer resumes from sleep, however, the default audio devices get a bit messed up. The default is set as EasyEffects EQ but audio goes **only** to EasyEffects because that is the default audio sink.

Normally the device which is set as default is my normal analog sink. When I use pavucontrol to fix this, if I set my analog sink as default, audio only goes through it, **without the eq**, *but if I then set the default to EasyEffects EQ*, it works fine. Though it was the default before, it only worked after setting my analog sink as default and then the EQ as default.

I'm trying to make a script using systemd for this problem, which does that: set My analog sink as default using pactl and then set my EQ sink as default. The problem with this is that the target that makes the service run after coming back from sleep is only available to a normal systemd service, and not to a "--user" systemd service. How do I fix this? If I try running it as a "user" systemd service it works but it does not autostart after resuming from sleep. If I run it as a normal systemd service, it does not work because "sudo pactl" does not work, even if I specify "User" and "Environment" in the systemd service.

Is there any other way to make it run after suspend? Or maybe make the normal (root) systemd service run that specific command as *my user* without any root privileges?

**script to run after resuming from suspend:**

```
#! /usr/bin/sh

pactl set-default-sink alsa_output.pci-0000_09_00.3.analog-stereo
pactl set-default-source alsa_input.pci-0000_09_00.3.analog-stereo
sleep 20
pactl set-default-sink easyeffects_sink
pactl set-default-source easyeffects_source
```

Comment: In your `systemd` script, running as `root`, you could `sudo -u $USER -i /path/to/myscript`. Read `man sudo`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a script under `/usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep`; the name doesn't matter but it must be owned by root and have the executable permission.
2. Systemd will invoke the same script both *before* and *after* suspend, passing the first argument as either "pre" or "post" to indicate which.
3. From within your script, which will be run as root, you can use `sudo` (or `su`, depending on your preference) to kick off a second script as another user

e.g.

```
sudo touch /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/custom-suspend.sh;
sudo chmod 744 /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/custom-suspend.sh;
```

Example script:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin

if [[ "${1}" == "post" ]]; then
    #AFTER resume

    # version 1
    sudo -u someuser -i /path/to/script2.sh

    # alternative version
    # su - someuser -c /path/to/script2.sh
fi
```

Source for systemd info:
https://blog.christophersmart.com/2016/05/11/running-scripts-before-and-after-suspend-with-systemd/

Comment: Thanks a lot! After some trial and error I ended up making another script but your answer led me to the solution. I did not know there was such thing as sudo -u and the system-sleep folder. I gotta learn a lot about UNIX and Linux still!

Comment: You're using `/bin/sh`, but `[[` is `bash` syntax. You should either change the shebang to `/bin/bash`, or use the `[` command instead.

Comment: @MartinvonWittich done

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the answer above, I managed to make it work!
I created a script in /lib/systemd/system-sleep/easyeffects after reading this https://github.com/wwmm/easyeffects/issues/1304 and using the script mentioned there. It didn't work, so I modified it with the info provided in this topic and it worked! Below are the scripts. The first one is the one from that GitHub issue and the last one is the one that worked for me

```
# easyeffects - systemd suspend/resume hook

case $1 in
    pre)  pkill easyeffects ;;
    post) easyeffects --gapplication-service  ;;
esac



#!/bin/sh

# easyeffects - systemd suspend/resume hook

case $1 in
    pre)  pkill easyeffects ;;
    post) sudo -u USER-NAME DISPLAY=:0 XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000 easyeffects --gapplication-service ;;
esac
```

Comment: What if another user (not USER-NAME) requests suspending?